# Session expired, please login again

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, adminer

I am using

Adminer 4.1.0 in Wordpress Plugin

OS is Ubuntu

Webserver is Nginx

The day before yesterday, my adminer is working properly. But yesterday i cannot login because it's returning an error message:

```
Session expired, please login again.
```

I searched google but i couldn't find any solution. Please help. What should i check? Thank you.

Comment: did you try other browser? to check if it is same problem?

Comment: @Markipe I tried with other browser, it's the same.

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-keeps-logging-out-problem/

Answer (score 11):

I also had this problem, plus when I did login and tried to change anything it threw an `Invalid CSRF token` error.  Got the solution from this thread;

https://sourceforge.net/p/adminer/discussion/960418/thread/17b3972a/

I edited adminer and explicitly added in the session save path for the server;

```
ini_set('session.save_path',  '/tmp/');
```

Comment: Make sure the tmp folder is exist. If not then first make a folder and give a permission.

Answer (score 8):

This may also occur when there is no disc space available

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but answering for others with same problem who end up here.

Make sure nginx has write permissions to the php session storage directory. Just had to do this on my CentOS box because a php upgrade set the session storage root:apache and changing it to root:nginx did the trick.

Comment: on my centos system i had to change all the apache group ownership to nginx in /var/lib/php/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but I guess you get the session expired message when trying to login to your wp-admin?

Also I'm not familiar with Adminer, but you are using it as a Wordpress plugin, so you can easily deactivate it, if you have FTP access.

Go to 'wp-content/plugins/' and locate the Adminer directory. Rename it, for example add '-old' to the directory name. This will disable the plugin, and you should have access to your wp-admin again.

For a real solution, I recommend you contact the Adminer devs.